# How to add url slugs when we don't know the slug?

Tags: htaccess

I am currently making a url shortener site where I will be able to shorten links and then get the shortened URL and its unique id stored on the database. [This](https://test-shortly-com.stackstaging.com/)(it isn't wholly ready) is where I have hosted it for testing. Now, when I try adding a slug to it, I get an issue that this does not exist.

[image]

I guess this can be done using the `.htaccess` file, but I have no idea how it works. The task for me could be easier if I specified the slug like `mainUrl.com/abc` or anything like that, but in my case, the slug can change to anything in this format:

```
www.mainUrl.com/randomIdOfTheUrl
```

Also, I have no idea about adding a dynamic slug.

Here is my code

script.js:

```
function createShortUrl(longUrl, isLoggedIn) {
    const shortUrl = randomString(10);
    set(ref(db, "Urls/" + shortUrl), {
        actualUrl: document.getElementById("link-input").value,
        shortUrl: shortUrl,
    })
        .then(() => {
            const view = document.getElementById("link-preview");
            document.getElementById("link-text-preview").textContent = longUrl;
            document.getElementById("shortened-link").textContent =
                "link.shortly.in/" + shortUrl;
            view.style.display = "flex";
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            alert(
                "Link could not be created due to some issues on our side. Please try again or if it does not work, try again later"
            );
            console.log("Fail: " + error);
        });
}

function randomString(length) {
    var letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
    var rString = "";
    var i = 0;
    while (i < length) {
        var letterIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length);
        var letter = letters.charAt(letterIndex);
        rString = rString + letter;
        i++;
    }
    return rString;
}
```

and the other one which looks for links and the decides which page to be shown, the main page or the redirecting page.

link-checker.js

```
const showUrlView = document.getElementById("link-opener");
const mainView = document.getElementById("mainContainer");
const lastUrlSegment = currentUrl.split("/")[currentUrl.split("/").length - 1];
console.log(`Last segment ${lastUrlSegment}`);

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCqhOLwA2VJXJNPSmXq7Bfp3lnpMEksljw",
    authDomain: "shorty-eea1d.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "shorty-eea1d",
    storageBucket: "shorty-eea1d.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "379580693572",
    appId: "1:379580693572:web:8fa99035bc12cfe03e9011",
};
const db = getDatabase();

initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const dbref = ref(db);
if (lastUrlSegment == "") {
    mainView.style.display = "block";
} else {
    get(child(dbref, "Urls/" + lastUrlSegment)).then((snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            showUrlView.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            mainView.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
```

also, here is the main body of my HTML so it becomes easy

[image]

Comment: This is being closed because it appears you already answered this on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73259147/how-to-add-dynamic-slugs-in-htaccess). In the future, please [only post questions to one Stack Exchange site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-que). If you'd like to have it migrated to another site, then you can flag it to ask a moderator to migrate it for you.